# How do I transition my iOS app with auto-renewing subscriptions to non-renewing subscriptions?

Tags: in-app-purchase, transition, subscription

My update for my iOS app with auto-renewing subscriptions was rejected, and the reason is that I must switch to non-renewing subscriptions. I can do that, but I am not clear about how to transition. I have many subscribers with auto-renewing subscriptions, so what happens when a user updates to the non-renewing version and then their current subscription auto-renews? Do I have to still handle those subscriptions as before? Or what?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some basic guidelines:
- Don't let any new users subscribe using Auto. 
- If you're not already you should be using your server to store and verify receipts as apposed to doing it from the app. 
- When someone buys a a Non-Renew, you calculate the expiration. Not Apple. 
- `restoreCompletedTransactions` doesn't work with Non-Renewing Subscriptions (NRS).
- Apple requires you build a system to sync subscriptions across a person's multiple devices. Unlike ARS, NRS doesn't do that automatically. 
- They require that you implement an **optional** user/password system to accomplish this. 
- I was rejected for not properly complying. Ask me if you have questions. 
- As you probably know, only a user can cancel an auto-renewing subscription. Not you. Unless Apple wants to step in to help the transition. But you could encourage people to cancel they're ARS and purchase an NRS. It'll probably have to be done in two steps like that. You could even offer them 2 weeks free if they transition. You can do this now since, with NRS, you calculate the expiration date. Not Apple. 
- Since you'll have to have both types running for a while until everyone is switched. It's only fair to continue to honor the ARS expiration date. So you should calculate the expiration date by starting with the ARS expiration provided by Apple and then adding any NRS durations that have been purchased.  Being careful to extend it if a new ARS renewal appears.